# Redirect with Nestjs not working with external URL

Tags: typescript, redirect, nestjs, single-sign-on

I have an issue with **redirecting** to an external URL, while implementing an SSO Server with **NestJs**, to authenticate some of my frontend applications as well as some API.

The authentication flow has these steps:

- External UI redirects to SSO Server with redirect URL, for authentication.
- SSO redirects to the login page.
- User logs in with personal information.
- SSO verify user and uses the previous URL sent by UI, to redirect with JWT and profile.

In my Auth controller, I have this endpoint setup that gets called with the information to log in.

```
@Post('auth/login')
  async login(@Body() body, @Res() res: Response) {
    const authResponse = await this.authService.login(body.user, body.password);

    if (authResponse.error) {
      return res.render('login', {
        title: '',
        redirect: body.redirect,
        errors: [{ msg: authResponse.error }],
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect(`${body.redirect}?token=${authResponse.token}`);
    }
  }
```

When a user is validated and the redirect is called, nothing happens in the log of Nestjs and the page doesn't redirect anywhere.

Some of the URL strings I've tested are:

- http://google.cl
- http://localhost:4200

Things I've tried:

- I tried using HTTP code 200 before the URL in the redirect method and when I do, it gets redirected to a blank page with the message *"OK, redirecting to URL"*
- I also tried with the `@Redirect()` decorator with the same results.
- If I try to redirect to another endpoint of the SSO server it works fine, but the external URLs look like it doesn't work.
- I also tried appending the return before the res. redirect to the method.
  Example: return res.redirect(`${body.redirect}?token=${authResponse.token}`);

**EDIT**

Other things I've done that don't work either:

- Initially redirect to another internal method and use the new method to only redirect to external URL.
- Giving different HTTP codes in the redirect. 301, 302, 304, 200.

My cors configuration is setup like this:

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  });
```

does anybody have had this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying with different browsers I found that the issue was happening only in Chrome even in incognito mode and even after removing cache and hard reset.

I realized that I was getting another error saying:

```
Refused to send form data to 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".
```

since the error is talking about content security policy, I decided to remove Helmet from the Nestjs and that did the trick.

Since I'll be needing Helmet anyways, I'll have to find a way to handle this error by configuring Helmet correctly, but at least now the redirect is working fine.